# Why is Jenkins using so much memory?

Tags: linux, memory, jenkins

I just started `htop` in my VPS and filtered to Jenkins to see if this was what was taking so much memory. Holy crap?!

I only have two build executors and only ran the service once (on machine bootup), so...why is this?

[image: what the hell?]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I only have 1 gig of ram on this VPS and I need to run Apache, Nexus, and Jenkins. Why is Jenkins being such a hog of resources like this? How can I counter it?

Also, if it helps, I *am* polling SCM every 30 minutes for changes in Jenkins, but that couldn't be responsible... could it?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you think you are seeing and why you think that's a problem?

Comment: Those are mostly threads. Press `t` to get a tree view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ant target `build-parallel`?

Try changing to the target `build` without parallelism

Answer (score 0):

Specify the max Java heap memory to be used by Jenkins at the startup, append the below command in Jenkins startup :

--env JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx512m"